Correct method of determining offset when doing multi level page table walking
On this page, I see the following code for determining the address of a page table entry:
uint64_t pde = 0;
uint64_t pd = ((virtualAddress >> 30) & (0x1ffll));

ReadPhysicalAddress((pdpe & PMASK) + 8 * pd, &pde, sizeof(pde), &readsize);

Here, pd is being multiplied by 8 to get to the pde.
However, we are not multiplying by 8 or any other integer in this code snippet:
if (pde & 0x80)
    return (pde & (~0ull << 42 >> 12)) + (virtualAddress & ~(~0ull << 30));

And in this one:
return ( pte.Bits.PhysicalAddress << PAGE_4KB_SHIFT )
         + virtAddr.Bits.PageIndex;

What is the rationale behind multiplying by 8 when going from one page table entry to another but not doing the same thing when calculating page addresses?
